# What does it mean to extend a function by zero outside of its domain?

Tags: notation

I have a function $f:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}^n$ with compact support in a domain $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$..  I don't know what it means to extend $f$ by zero outside $\Omega$, I've never heard of that before.  If somebody could tell me what this means then that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just define it to be $0$ outside $\Omega$, you will need to verify that it is smooth on the boundary $\partial\Omega$.

Comment: @lEm Why assume that it needs to be smooth at the boundary?  I can extend a function by zero, even if the domain of that function is not a smooth manifold (or any other kind of space which admits a smooth structure).  The context of the question implies that the subject of study is DEs, where smoothness is a desirable property, but this is a distinct issue from "extending by zero".

Answer (score 1):

After having spent some time searching, I cannot find an obvious dupe target for this question.  I am, frankly, quite surprised by this.  However, it is not an unreasonable question, and I think it deserves to be answered on MSE.  I am going to answer a slightly more general question:

> What does it mean to "extend a function"?

Suppose that $\Omega \subsetneq X$ and that a function
$$ f : \Omega \to Y $$
is given.  That is, suppose that we are given a function which is defined only on a subset of a smaller set.  Given such a function, it is reasonable to ask if there is a natural way of defining $f$ so that it "makes sense" on all of $X$, instead of just a subset.  If there is a way of doing this, the result is called an "extension" of $f$.  Somewhat more formally:

> *Definition:* Let $\Omega \subsetneq X$ and suppose that $f : \Omega \to Y$.  An *extension* of $f$ is a function $\tilde{f} : X \to Y$ such that
>   $$ \tilde{f}(x) = f(x) \quad\forall x\in\Omega. $$

In other words, $\tilde{f}$ (the extension of $f$) is a new function defined on a larger set than $f$, but which agrees with $f$ on the set where where *both* functions are defined.  Another way of saying this is that the restricttion of $\tilde{f}$ to $\Omega$ is $f$:
$$ \tilde{f}|_{\Omega} = f. $$
We can then "extend a function by [blank]", where [blank] describes some property which we want $\tilde{f}$ to have.  So, to give a couple of examples:

- To *extend $f$ by zero*, we define $\tilde{f}$ to be zero away from $\Omega$.  That is, we define
  $$ \tilde{f} : X \to Y : x \mapsto \begin{cases} f(x) & \text{if $x\in \Omega$, and} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases} $$
  In other words, when we extend a function by zero, we simply define the extension to be zero away from the set of interest.
- To *extend $f$ by continuity*, we define $\tilde{f}$ so that it is continuous on $X$.  For this to work, we must assume that $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, and, as it wouldn't really make sense to extend a discontinuous function by continuity, we typically also assume that $f$ is continuous on $\Omega$.  An elementary example of this might be exponential function:  for a fixed (positive) constant it is not too difficult to define
  $$ \exp_c : \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R} : \frac{p}{q} \mapsto \sqrt[q]{c^p}, $$
  where
  $$ x^p := \prod_{j=1}^{p} x
  \qquad\text{and}\qquad
  \left(\sqrt[q]{x}\right)^q = x. $$
  This function can be extended by continuity to a function on $\mathbb{R}$ in order to get the usual notion of an exponential function on $\mathbb{R}$.
- To *extend $f$ analytically*, we define $\tilde{f}$ so that it is analytic on $X$.  This notion comes up a lot in complex analysis:  if $\Omega \subsetneq \mathbb{C}$ and $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ is an analytic function, then we might want to know if it is possible to extend $f$ to a function which is analytic on a larger domain.  The Riemann zeta function is an example of such a beast:  for real $s > 1$, we can define
  $$ \zeta(s) := \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} j^{-s}. $$
  This function can then be extended to a function which is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$.  The properties of this extension are of tremendous interest in number theory. :)